# Is using curly braces in variables good practice in php

Tags: php, coding-style

Some developers uses curly braces in their PHP code and some simply concatenates them.

For example, these 2 lines of code are totally valid in PHP

```
echo "<h1>{$row['title']}</h1>";

echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
```

The output of the code is the same at the end end but which one is consider a good coding practice?

Thank you, J

Comment: I personally prefer concatenating as it makes the markup easier to read. Not sure if there's any benefits either way though.

Comment: I'm using `sprintf` for things like this. Anything longer than one-liners and I switch to using a template engine.

Comment: @Adam: Modern editors can pick out PHP variables in strings and highlight them accordingly, which makes the extra concatenation harder on the eyes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using curly brace syntax is slightly slower. Consider the following test:

```
<?php

  $array = array('key'=>'val');

  $start1 = microtime(TRUE);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $str = "<tag>{$array['key']}</tag>";
  }
  $end1 = microtime(TRUE);
  $result1 = $end1 - $start1;

  $start2 = microtime(TRUE);
  for ($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
    $str = "<tag>".$array['key']."</tag>";
  }
  $end2 = microtime(TRUE);
  $result2 = $end2 - $start2;

  $start3 = microtime(TRUE);
  for ($k = 0; $k < 100000; $k++) {
    $str = '<tag>'.$array['key'].'</tag>';
  }
  $end3 = microtime(TRUE);
  $result3 = $end3 - $start3;

  echo "1: $result1\n2: $result2\n3: $result3\n";

?>
```

On my PHP/5.2.19-win32 system, the first test (with curly braces) is slightly slower (~7%). However, the difference is so small as to be not worth worrying about, and I would say do whatever you are most comfortable with.

Slightly counter-intuitively, the second test is consistently faster than the third (~2%) - double quotes are faster than single quotes - and I would have expected it to be the other way around.

Comment: Absolute difference between these tests is equal to about 0.007 second or 7 milliseconds on a 100000 run. You spend ten fold more time just typing one dot.

Comment: Yeah, win32 systems are especially slow with curly braces, but only if they contain array keys with lowercase letters and in daylight saving time. If you switch the order of the tests, you'll see another difference. The results vary with each request anyway. I have the feeling that such kind of tests are not saying much at all, I wonder how they related to good practice, if they smell so much as bad practice: http://codepad.org/dzuQstX1

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for your answer, I never thought about speed. Speed if important for me and I want to make my code as optimized as possible. I have notice you are using Windows. I am using CentOS does the performances will be similar?

Comment: @Jimmy: This answer is not about speed. It only looks like it is. Don't get blended. Instead take care about your code that it is self-documenting, easy to read and to maintain and that you don't mix output with business logic. Your question can not be specifically answered, as there is no best practice on how to combine strings. Micro-optimizations are however bad practice. Don't let yourself get fooled.

Comment: @daverandom: I agree, I think it's easier to read when it's concatenated but why not make it faster as well! for me, that is best practices

Answer (score 7):

It's useless to ask for best practice, as you have not written which style you prefer. If it helps you to read your strings with curly brackets, use them, they work. There are multiple ways to solve the problem, just to name a few:

```
echo "<h1>{$row['title']}</h1>";

echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";

echo "<h1>", $row['title'], "</h1>";

printf("<h1>%s</h1>", $row['title']);

echo sprintf("<h1>%s</h1>", $row['title']);

?><h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1><?php # thx, Jaime :)

...
```

Choose what is readable for you. Best practices you learn while doing. The language is a tool to suit your needs.

Comment: If you are separating the variables from the text isn't it better to use single quotes? I understood that told the parser to not look for variables and sped up code.

Comment: There's also `?><h1><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h1><?php`

Comment: @Drazisil: Define better. In 99.999% of the time the ' vs. " blah blah is - drastic wording ahead for a reason - professional bullshitting.

Comment: If you aren't concerned about performance, why are you nit-picking my answer? This question is about what is better, and I stated my choice.

Comment: Oh my comment below your question was just a question, not nit-picking. I was interested what made you choose that way. It's totally okay as far as I can say, it should work :). Just was curious about the motivation, not execution speed.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the misinterpretation then :)

Answer (score 4):

I've always found the echo `'<h1>' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';` easier to read.

Comment: Why do you concatenate the strings for echo?

Comment: I've found with syntax highlighting it's easier to spot my variables.

Comment: Yes, could be. But why are you concatenating? Why don't you use just a comma? Isn't that supported by your syntax highlighter?

Comment: Never noticed that was an option.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, using single quotes for strings is more efficient in PHP.

So, I would say no, using curly braces around variables in string is not a good practice.

Using the following syntax is both more efficient and more readable (imho) :

```
echo '<h1>' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used curly brackets around variables myself, ever. Just seems very long winded to me!

Comment: How is it long winded - the curly brace is one character and the end quote and . are two characters? I think the concatenation is more obvious and possibly therefore more clear, but not more concise...

Comment: curlies are highly useful. Try `$arr[0][1] = 'hello'; echo "$arr[0][1]", "\n", "{$arr[0][1]}";` and compare the difference. (A contrived case, but a good demo).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in that, unless you don't properly escape user-submitted HTML, which you can forget to do in either case.

Some may say that single quotes are more efficient, but all tests I see were made years ago on that old hardware, which doesn't speaks for their credibility. Tests on current hardware show that single quotes on a 100000 run is only *7 milliseconds* faster than curly braces, which [can't be an argument](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html).

Use what you think is more readable because developer's time these days is much more expensive than a computer time. Let you servers do their jobs.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an agreed upon standard already, I recommend you use an existing one such as [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) or [Pear](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). For example, with respect to your question, the [Zend guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html) specifically states:

Variable substitution is permitted using either of these forms:

```
$greeting = "Hello $name, welcome back!";

$greeting = "Hello {$name}, welcome back!";
```