# Is it legal omitting braces in inline PHP?

Tags: php

**With braces:**

`<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if (isset($text)) { echo $text; } ?>" />`

**Without braces:**

`<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if (isset($text)) echo $text; ?>" />`

Both are working fine and give no errors. But out of curiosity, I would like to know which one is the best practice?

Comment: You mean `{}` of if ?

Comment: I would say not writting inline code at all ist best practice :-)

Comment: It's legal because you only have one statement as the if body. Having said that, i would not inline code, rather, do the logic before and simply print the result.

Comment: @Zim84, What is the reason and causes?

Comment: @Elikill58 - Yes, the curly braces!

Comment: Ok, Does this answer your question? [Is using curly braces in variables good practice in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419789/is-using-curly-braces-in-variables-good-practice-in-php)

Comment: @Elikill58 - The post talks about the braces around a variable. It's not relevant to my question. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry...

Comment: Best practise is not mixing HTML and PHP code

Comment: @NicoHaase - Then please tell me how to print the input value after the form reload?

Comment: @Sakkir he means not mixing complex code logic and output, logic first and higher, output later in view and it's right practice

Comment: @SarDauMort - I didn't mean to offend her. I just wanted to know if there are any alternate ways. Her phrase `Best practise is not mixing HTML and PHP code`, does include all kinds of PHP codes. That's how anyone can understand. When she said that, I thought there could be a better way to do this. Anyways, she didn't say anything as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use such code without adding braces. But only for simple actions like printing something or execute some single command. If your inline PHP code contains more logic you **should** use braces just because of how this language works.

```php
<!-- This is correct -->
<?php if (isset($text)) echo $text ?>

<!-- Here you have more statements, you should use braces -->
<?php if (isset($text)) { $text = trim($text); echo $text; } ?>
```

But it's still better to not create long multi-line statements like this in inline tag. Best practice is transform all required actions before rendering.

```php
<?php
  if (isset($text))
    $text = trim($text);
?>
<!-- Here some other content rendered -->
<?php if (isset($text)) echo $text; ?>
```

Comment: Which version is more perfect? With braces or without braces?

Comment: I prefer to not to use braces in single-line code. And don't make multiline statements in single line. Because it's harder to read and understand. Also it's better when logic is separated from content rendering like in second code block.

Answer (score 2):

Better practice to use short one for output:

```
<?= $output ?? null; ?>
```

And in multi lines / complex logic

```
<?php
$output = null;
if ($condition) {
    $output = 1;
    //some code
    if ($anotherCondition) {
         $output = 2;
    }
}
?>
```

And in input

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="<?= $output ?>" />
```

This will keep code clean and supportive for future developers :)

Answer (score 1):

It is legal to use without braces for single line actions. The statement right next to the `if` will be considered as the body of the condition.

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if (isset($text)) echo $text; ?>" />
```

For multiline actions, braces are compulsory. I prefer it is always better to use the braces to avoid confusions in future.

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="<?php if (isset($text)) { echo $text;echo $someothertext; } ?>" />
```

Otherwise you can use the colon and end for both single line and multiline statements as below:

```
if(a < 1 ) :
    echo "a is less than 1";
    echo "a="+a;
endif;
```